# News targeting - Department based (using Target Audience)

Tags: user-profile-service, audience-targeting

I would like to have a news page that are targetted to certain department (news page currently is based on publishing pages)

I was thinking of using Target Audience feature
But not sure if using target audience will work if I'm going to be displaying the news usinga custom webpart e.g using rest api
I'm not sure but I think the target audience only works if being used only with out of the box webpart

What would be the most practical way to target news based on departments(the depts are list in userprofile)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Target audience is an OOB list view web part property and is used to hide or display the current web part on the basis of current user permissions/ member of specific SharePoint groups. 
So theoretically if you are going to develop a custom web part, you will not have this property by default. You need to add your custom property in your custom web part with some functionality.
I think below link will help you set up custom property for your custom web part

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/11/10/how-to-programmatically-set-the-target-audience-on-a-web-part.aspx

Comment: Thanks Prasad.How can this be achieved client side with no server side code.

Comment: For the Client side code, you have to create the client app part with the custom property, refer http://www.sharepointyammertech.com/2014/06/sharepoint-2013-add-custom-properties.html